# Assign all the computer's power to Python

Tags: python, cpu

I'm running a python program that finds all the prime numbers. Is it possible to allocate all the computer's power to this single task. By using all the 4 cores that my processor have?

Thanks!

p.s. I'm using Linux of course!

The code I'm using is:

```
nextCheck = time.time() + 60
primesFound = 0
while 1:
    if isPrime(toTest):
        open("primeList.txt", "a").write(str(toTest)+"\n")
        primesFound += 1
    toTest += 2

    if (toTest+1) % 1000 == 0:
        if time.time() >= nextCheck:
            print "Average speed: " + str(float(primesFound)/((time.time()-nextCheck)+60)) + "/s"
            primesFound = 0
            nextCheck = time.time() + 60
```

Comment: Are you using threads or multiprocessing? You cannot hope to make use of multiple cores if you are using a single-threaded application.

Comment: Do you mean primitive abundant number? or prime number? In either case, finding all of them is impossible (there is an infinite amount of both...), even if you're running on linux.

Comment: You could code your application in C (which is quite often much faster than Python on current implementations), and you should consider multi-threading (i.e. [pthreads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads)) or multi-processing and perhaps also using the GPGPU e.g. with [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opencl)

Comment: Apparently, the Electronic Frontier Foundation is offering a $150,000 prize for the first 100-million-digit prime number (which is known to exist). Once you've found that, you can buy a bigger computer...

Comment: And how is `isPrime` defined? There are some clever mathematical algorithms (better that Erasthothene's sieve) to compute primes.

Answer (score 2):

Use `multiprocessing`. If you are using CPython, only one thread at a time can execute Python bytecode so using threads isn't that much help.

If you can e.g. write a simple function to test a number, you can use a `multiprocessing.Pool` object's `map()` method to apply that function to a list of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign a higher priority to your Python process using nice:

```
nice -n -20 python app.py
```

... that will help, but will not guarantee that you are squeezing out all the power from your computer.

For that code, the best you can try is:

1. do not write numbers directly to an output file and save them in a memory structure,
2. program an event for not checking all the time about whether you need to print the speed statistics or not,
3. try to split out in several concurrent tasks the operations performed within function "isPrime" for executing them as separte tasks.

... however, I do not know whether this application worths this effort.

Comment: That `nice -n -20` won't help much, unless the system load is high enough to have many *runnable* processes competing for the CPU (which is not the case on a common desktop).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch in a desktop is precisely a place where you have lots of processes competing for the usage of the CPU. For example, you will have all the processes concerning the graphical execution of the desktop itself, web navigator.. just execute "top" in a console and you will see how many of them you have right now...

Comment: I wrote about *runnable* processes. I do have a lot of processes (about 250), but most of them are nearly idle.... My current load is about 0.15....